# SQL CASE statement only updates one value froom join table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do a case statement to update multiple columns, but only the first value from my join table AS 'b' is getting picked up. Below I have EDLCode = 1 and this value gets picked up. If I set the EDLCode = 2, it does not update anything. I can separate the updates into it's own blocks and those update correctly, but I was hoping to combine and make this code a little more condense. Any ideas?

```
UPDATE mainTable
    SET 
        col_one = CASE WHEN EDLCode = 1 THEN b.Amount END,
        col_two = CASE WHEN EDLCode = 2 THEN b.Amount END

FROM #mainDataTable AS a
INNER JOIN #deductLiabData AS b
    ON a.Employee = b.Employee 
WHERE b.EDLType = 'D'
```

Result would be:

```
EDLCode   Amount
1           100
2           200

col_one     col_two
100           null
```

Comment: `b.EDLCode`, by any chance?

Comment: @JeroenMostert tried and failed unfortunately.

Comment: Table definitions and sample data would help considerably here. My guess is that your case expressions need an `ELSE` but it is hard to know for sure.

Comment: Why would col_two be NULL if you have a row that contains EDL_CODE = 2? Shouldn't that be 200? NULL is likely what you get now for one of those columns because of the 1:M join.

Comment: @SMor - yes, it should be 200 since EDL_Code = 2, but I can't see why it's only showing 1. I know it's the join, just can't figure out why since my joins look correct.

Comment: A [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_ will return `null` if you don't provide an `else` value (or cover all of the possible cases). Perhaps you would like that to be the existing column value, e.g. `col_one = CASE WHEN EDLCode = 1 THEN b.Amount ELSE col_one END`?

Comment: In this situation, a row in main joins to multiple rows in deduct. You are trying to conditionally update that row in main with values from different rows in deduct. That just is not possible as written. Only one row will be used for the update and you can no control over which will be used. Hence the values are wrong when you check after the update succeeds. And I did not mention that there might be multiple rows that contain a given EDLCode (e.g., 2). You might use an aggregate (like MIN) or TOP 1 to do this. A repro script would be helpful.